# Python Scrollbars on text widget in grid layout

Tags: python, text, scrollbar

So I have a text widget with multiple lines populated. I have the following code that creates the text widget, scrollbar and assigns them to each other. However, right now the text box has disappeared and the scroll bar is scrunched up real small. What's wrong?

```
txt_domains = Text(root,height=10,width=20)
txt_domains.grid(row=1,column=1)
scr_domains = Scrollbar(txt_domains,orient='vertical')
scr_domains.grid(row=1,column=2)
txt_domains.config(yscrollcommand=scr_domains.set)
scr_domains.config(command=txt_domains.yview)
```

**UPDATE:**
Using the following modification:

```
txt_domains = Text(root,height=10,width=20)
txt_domains.grid(row=1,column=1)
scr_domains = Scrollbar(root,orient='vertical')
scr_domains.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='sn')
txt_domains.config(yscrollcommand=scr_domains.set)
scr_domains.config(command=txt_domains.yview)
```

I know get this result:
[image: Python Scroll Bar]

For some reason everything shifted over? **SOLUTION:** Change the txt_domains to column=0 and scrollbar to column=1.

Comment: Try making the scrollbar's parent be root instead of the text.

Comment: Have you checked (Python mega widgets) pmw.ScrolledText_2 or pmw.ScrolledText?

Comment: Thanks @dusty, for the comment. That was part of the problem. I also had to make it sticky ns. But for some reason everything is moved over now.

Comment: @Marcin, I am not familiar with either of those two widgets but I'm trying to not use external libraries as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the parent of your scrollbar is `txt_domains` instead of frame or root window (depend on your code). This should work well:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()


txt_domains = Text(root,height=10,width=20)
txt_domains.grid(row=1,column=1)
scr_domains = Scrollbar(root,orient='vertical')
scr_domains.grid(row=1,column=2, sticky=S+N)
txt_domains.config(yscrollcommand=scr_domains.set)
scr_domains.config(command=txt_domains.yview)


root.mainloop()
```